# AWS ELB fails healthcheck with http ports other than 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We've been using AWS for a while and have also setup many ELB's.  The problem we have is that we have multiple sites running on multiple servers.  All IIS 7.5 sites are on each of 3 web servers.  We utilize ports 80 and 443 with all bindings for sites setup correctly with domains/subdomains.  We have an ELB for each site.

The problem we have is that each ELB is currently setup with a healthcheck of HTTP:80/ so each ELB is not really checking the health of it's respective site.

What we'd like to do is setup each site to listen to a different extra port (i.e., 8082, 8083, etc.) and have each ELB's healthcheck check the site's extra port (i.e., HTTP:8082/, HTTP:8083/, etc.).  The ports are opened on the firewalls and in the security groups correctly and we can hit each site on their respective extra port (i.e., http://web1.mysite.com:8082/).

AWS's documentation says you should be able to do what we're trying to do, but the healthchecks of the instances don't pass.  I've even gone so far as to define a listener for the respective port.  Just to confirm, I can set the check to be HTTP:80/ and the instance comes "InService", but when I change it to HTTP:8082/, it immediately goes out of service.  This is driving me nuts so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We determined that we can fix this by setting up each site's extra port binding to it's corresponding port with a blank host name.  Also, by assuring that the "Default Site" is turned off (in our case it was).  The binding hostname was set to the site's name before (i.e., www.mysite.com).